# Are there some international laws which are used to govern election processes in all democracies?

Tags: election, democracy, government

For example, it would be naive to suppose that all the laws of an election process in USA are the same as those in Croatia.

So, it seems it is better to suppose that there are some laws specific for each democracy but also that there are some laws which are internationally valid and are typical of each and every democracy.

I am interested in those international laws, that is, in laws of the election processes which are required of every and each democracy just because it is a democracy.

Do such laws exist?

Comment: The simple answer is: **no**. Even defining the **democracy** itself is controversial up to some point that sometimes obviously totalitarian regimes call themselves a true democracy system, such as Iran, North Korea, China, etc.

Answer (score 4):

There are ["election monitors"](https://www.democraticaudit.com/2017/11/13/international-election-observers-the-watchdogs-with-no-bite/), but they have no enforcement powers.

The UN [Universal Declaration of Human Rights](https://www.un.org/en/universal-declaration-human-rights/) specifies a right to elections:

> The will of the people shall be the basis of the authority of government; this will shall be expressed in periodic and genuine elections which shall be by universal and equal suffrage and shall be held by secret vote or by equivalent free voting procedures

Obviously this isn't universally observed, given the large number of UN countries which do not hold free elections.

Comment: What does it mean for elections to not be free? I mean, what are non-free elections?

Comment: @Ante That's another opinion based question, but at a minimum many people would want more than one viable option to vote for, and a lack of direct repercussions for their choice.

Comment: @Ante a "free" election is one in which any adult (with very few limitations) can stand as a candidate, operate a party organisation, and the voters are free to choose via a secret ballot which is properly counted. This looks like a definition from OSCE: https://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/16815?download=true

Comment: @origimbo: Some may even argue that you'd want more than two viable options, for every voter. That definition of course would make the US presidential elections in its current form non-democratic (even in swing states, there are only 2 candidates, and most voters don't matter at all).